# Group NSArray results by date for tableview sections

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have the following NSArray, with the array i would like to group all the objects that containing the same date. I want to group these objects and then display them in a TableView, with that group the object with the same dates in their own sections in the TableView. In each section i want the events to be listed by the time in which the event will occur starting from earliest to latest time.

The data retrieved is from a Parse Database. (Not sure if this matters).

Below is the Array Results

```
DATA (

"<Sessions:QtJKSToEu9:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-19 18:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Seating assignment on name badge.\";\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = \"Dinner and CARE Awards Celebration\";\n}",

"<Sessions:btZ5eRZffl:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-19 20:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Brief meeting\";\n    location = \"Cedar Room\";\n    name = \"Store Manager Advisory Board Members\";\n}",

"<Sessions:HY4VtgBncd:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 07:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = Breakfast;\n    location = Ballrooms;\n    name = Breakfast;\n}",

"<Sessions:6p6t2uL5Jf:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 11:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = Lunch;\n    location = Ballrooms;\n    name = Lunch;\n}",

"<Sessions:TpEHi5Glsk:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 17:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Cocktails - Ballroom Pre-Function Area\";\n    location = Ballroom;\n    name = Cocktails;\n}",

"<Sessions:e9yEi6vFoE:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 18:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Welcome from Tony Kenney followed by dinner\";\n    location = Ballrooms;\n    name = Welcome;\n    speaker = \"Tony Kenney\";\n}",

"<Sessions:kTG4NemPX4:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 19:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"We Are Speedway Awards Night\";\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = \"Awards Night\";\n}",

"<Sessions:L9I8BIVECe:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-21 07:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = Breakfast;\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = Breakfast;\n}",

"<Sessions:WUGRHDpHyo:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-21 12:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = Lunch;\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = Lunch;\n}",

"<Sessions:r61f5NZr66:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-21 09:15:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Marketing Breakouts \\U2013 Rotation\\no\\tStart times for rotations:  9:15, 9:50, 10:25, 11:00, 11:35\\no\\tPlease see your name tag for your Group #2 room assignment.\\no\\tThe speaker will direct you to your next session.\\n\";\n    location = Various;\n    name = \"Marketing Breakouts \";\n}",

"<Sessions:RXkIDNIYoQ:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 13:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"o\\tPlease see your name tag for your Group #1 room assignment\";\n    location = Various;\n    name = \"Division Breakouts\";\n}",

"<Sessions:lLI2PxdCdx:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-21 13:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Closing Comments by Tony Kenny\";\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = \"Closing Comments\";\n    speaker = \"Tony Kenny\";\n}",

"<Sessions:KWz7Xen5a6:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 13:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Special Guest Speaker Gary Heminger\";\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = \"Special Guest Speaker\";\n    speaker = \"Gary Heminger\";\n}",

"<Sessions:AU1x3LlUrF:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-21 08:30:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Marketing Focus by Tom LeFevers\";\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = \"Marketing Focus\";\n    speaker = \"Tom LeFevers\";\n}",

"<Sessions:36TIRrD0s5:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-20 08:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Operations Focus by Glenn Plumby\";\n    location = \"Center Stage\";\n    name = \"Operations Focus\";\n    speaker = \"Glenn Plumby\";\n}",

"<Sessions:tTvppNFM7L:(null)> {\n    date = \"2013-11-19 17:00:00 +0000\";\n    description = \"Cocktails \\U2013 Center Stage pre-function area. NOTE: Group photographs scheduled for select field personnel\\nin the lobby bar. (Appointment time on name badge.)\";\n    location = \"Center Stage pre-function area \";\n    name = Cocktails;\n}"
```

)

How can i group the objects that contain the same date for example "2013-11-19" all into one section?

**UPDATE** With Artur Answers + Slight modification to fit my needs

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
int section = 0;

dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
[dataSource addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];

for (int i = 0; i < _events.count - 1; i++) {
    EventInfo *firstEvent = _events[i];
    EventInfo *secondEvent = _events[i+1];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM, dd"];

    NSString *firstDateString = [df stringFromDate:firstEvent.details.date];
    NSString *secondDateString = [df stringFromDate:secondEvent.details.date];


    sectionArray = dataSource[section];

    if (![sectionArray containsObject:firstEvent]) {
        [sectionArray addObject:firstEvent];
    }
    if (![firstDateString compare:secondDateString] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSMutableArray *newSection = [NSMutableArray array];
        [newSection addObject:secondEvent];
        [dataSource addObject:newSection];

        section++;
    }
   }
   [dataSource.lastObject addObject:_events.lastObject];
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think the OP wants to parse the data to retrieve the date, then use that to group the tableview rows.

Comment: @AustinMullins I know what they want to do. But telling us what they want to do is not the same as actually asking a question. As written, we have no idea what part of the huge list of requirements they need help with.

Comment: Well, first of all, did you search about sorting? Can you do it in the query? That could save some times. Then, your issue is about regrouping dates (for section) by what? Same day? Because the "like day" is quite unclear.

Comment: I have updated the question as to what i am trying to do. I do understand how to sort using built in functionality with Parse. I am trying to group the objects with identical dates into separate sections of a table view.

Comment: I upvoted this because I thought it was very helpful question, especially since OP posted his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];

// Sorting your array by date asc
array = [[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    YourObject *firstObject = obj1;
    YourObject *secondObject = obj2;

    return [secondObject.date compare:firstObject.date] == NSOrderedAscending;
}] mutableCopy];


int section = 0;
[dataSource addObject:[NSMutableArray array]]; //Adding first section

for (int i = 0; i < array.count - 1; i++) {
    YourObject *firstObject = array[i];
    YourObject *secondObject = array[i+1];

    NSDate *firstDate = [self dateWithoutTimePart:firstObject.date];
    NSDate *secondDate = [self dateWithoutTimePart:secondObject.date];

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = dataSource[section];

    if (![sectionArray containsObject:firstObject]) {
        [sectionArray addObject:firstObject];
    }
    if (![firstDate compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        NSMutableArray *newSection = [NSMutableArray array];
        [newSection addObject:secondObject];
        [dataSource addObject:newSection];

        section++;
    }
}

// Adding last object to last section
[dataSource.lastObject addObject:array.lastObject];
```

This is a fast written code, so sorry for possible mistakes :)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the post however could you explain it a little. This is all new to me and not quite sure why but when i get to the loop my array is empty. Actually before i even start sorting the array it is empty however only in the 
d
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

does it reflect a nil array all other methods the array _events_array contains the 16 objects from above.

Comment: because you must write that function :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to use your answer and modify it to fit my needs. Similar approach however the data i have is already ordered by date using Parse functionality. Sorry it took so long...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I use

```
class VC: UITableViewController {

var source: DataSource!
var monthList = [String]()
var monthDictionary = [String:[object]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ObjectCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ObjectCell")
    tableView.rowHeight = 60
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear
    organizeObjectsIntoSections() //The magic happens here!
}

func organizeObjectsIntoSections() {
    for object in source.object {
        if monthDictionary[object.date.monthString] == nil { // if you the dictionary does not have a key for that month, add it as an array
            monthDictionary[object.date.monthString] = [object]
        } else { // otherwise append it to the existing array
            monthDictionary[object.date.monthString]?.append(object)
        }
        if !monthList.contains(object.date.monthString) {
           monthList.append(object.date.monthString) 
        }
    }
    monthList = Array(monthDictionary.keys) // store the keys for easy reference

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return monthList[section] // number of keys i.e. months in the data set
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    guard let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .white
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 16)!
    header.textLabel?.textColor = .black
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return monthList.count // number of months stored in the dictionary
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return monthDictionary[monthList[section]]!.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ObjectCell", for: indexPath) as? ObjectCell
        else { return UITableViewCell() }
    let selectedObject = objectAt(indexPath)
    cell.configure(withObject: selectedObject)

    return cell
}

func objectAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> object {
    let month = monthList[indexPath.section]
    return ((monthDictionary[month]!) as [object])[indexPath.row]
}
}
```

Explanation:

1. Parse through the list and store objects in dictionaries based on their month
2. Store a list of those keys
3. Reference the object:

   - by accessing the key for the section `let key = monthList[indexPath.section]`
   - using that value to access the right object array `let objectArray = monthDictionary[key]`.
   - Finally, get the object by subscripting the array `objectArray[indexPath.row]`